# Redux Saga - Unable to cancel task

Tags: reactjs, generator, redux-saga

I have a react project set up to work with redux saga, but for some reason, I'm unable to cancel a running saga / action task. The expectancy is that, after some action, (like user navigating away, or clicking on a button), the running saga would be cancelled. Tried catching the cancelled action, but doesn't happen after the saga has run completely:

```
function* fetchOverviewSaga(): SagaReturnType<any> {
  try {
    yield delay(5000);
    
    console.log('still running');

    const response = yield call(getOverviewData);

    console.log('still running');

    yield all([
        put(updateTagsPendingState(false)),
        put(updateTagsDataState(response.items)),
      ]);

  } finally {
    if(yield cancelled()) {
      console.log('saga task canceled');
    }
  }
}

function* cancelOverviewSaga(): SagaReturnType<any> {
  const runningAction = yield fork(fetchOverviewSaga);

  yield cancel(runningAction);
}

function* overviewSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(startOverview, fetchOverviewSaga),
    takeLatest(cancelOverview, cancelOverviewSaga)
  ]);
}
```

The result is that, even after the action was dispatched for cancelling (cancelOverviewSaga), the fetchOverviewSaga still runs, do gets catched in the `if(yield cancelled())` only after it completely finished running. Not sure if this is the actual behaviour, would have expected to cancel when requested. Any ideas are most welcomed.

*Edit:

Upon calling the cancel action, the `fetchOverviewSaga`  seems to be canceled, since it does log `saga task canceled`, however the ones remaining to run is the block from `yield all([..]))`, looking at the console, probably the problem lies within that block

*Edit2:

To better illustrate the behaviour:

- dispatch startOverview action
- immediately cancel it
- the log: saga task canceled
- after 5000ms (the delay finishes in  fetchOverviewSaga)
- the log: 'still running' x2 and dispatches the yield all from fetchOverviewSaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same saga can run in multiple instances independently. So e.g. if you do

```js
const task1 = yield fork(mySaga);
const task2 = yield fork(mySaga);
task1 === task2 // false
```

it will run two independent instances of mySaga, each with its own task. If you cancel one, it doesn't cancel the other one. So forking and immediately canceling your `fetchOverviewSaga` saga in `cancelOverviewSaga` will have no effect on the saga that is running as a result of dispatching the `startOverview` action.

In this case you can instead use e.g. the `race` effect to achieve your goal:

```
function* fetchOverviewSaga() {
  try {
    // your fetching logic ...
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      console.log("saga task canceled");
    }
  }
}

function* startOverviewSaga() {
  yield race([
    call(fetchOverviewSaga),
    take(cancelOverview),
  ]);
}

function* overviewSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(startOverview, startOverviewSaga);
}
```

The race effect waits for one if the items in the array to finish and then it cancels all other ones, and so:

- If the `cancelOverview` action is disptached before the `fetchOverviewSaga` is finished it will cancel the `fetchOverviewSaga`
- If the `fetchOverviewSaga` finishes before a cancel action is dispatched it will just stop waiting for the cancel action.

Working demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-69717869-redux-saga-unable-to-cancel-task-vu4b0?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel a saga, all sub tasks cancel. Example:

```
function* mainTask(){
  const task = yield fork(subTask1) // or call
  yield cancel(task)
}

function* subTask1(){
  yield fork(subTask2) // or call
}

function* subTask2(){
  ...
}
```

In this example, since `cancel` propagates downward, `subTask1` will be cancelled through `mainTask` and `subTask2` will be cancelled through `subTask1`.

However, when you `yield put`, you dispatched an action, which is caught in a reducer or listened in a saga. This is just like sending an erroneous e-mail, and sending a second e-mail to fix the error. Therefore, you can dispatch another action inside `if (yield cancelled())` to undo what other actions do.

#### One way

```
  } finally {
    if(yield cancelled()) {
      yield all[
       put(cancelUpdateTagsPendingState()),
       put(cancelUpdateTagsDataState()),
      ]
    }
  }
```

### [Helpful docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation#task-cancellation)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, initially I though that once you hit the cancel, the whole task would cancel out, and jump to the yield canceled() block; this does happen, but in a wierd way still goes onwards in execution, not sure if this is correct though (added Edit 2 in the original question)